# Unable to res.render() with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

When trying to render my second page (services) I'm finding that it just renders the home page. I'm pretty new to express and node, so I can't see why.

```
import config from './config';
import apiRouter from './api';
import express from 'express';
const server = express();

import {home, services} from './serverRender';

server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
 var contents = home();
  res.render('index', {
  content: contents
 });
});
 server.get('/services', (req, res) => {
  var contents = services();
   res.render('services', {
   content: contents
 });
});


server.use(express.static('public'));


server.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.info('Express listening on port', config.port);
});
```

serverRender.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

import Home from './src/components/Home'
import Services from './src/components/Services'

import config from './config';

const home = () => {
    ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <Home />
    );
};
const services = () => {
    ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <Services />
    );
};




export  {home, services}
```

index.ejs and services.ejs(they got the same code)

```
<%- include('header') -%>
  <div id="root"><%- content -%></div>
<%- include('footer') -%>
```

config.js

```
const env = process.env

export const nodeEnv = env.NODE_ENV || 'development'


export default {
    port: env.PORT || 8080,
    host: env.HOST || '0.0.0.0',
    get serverUrl() {
        return `http://${this.host}:${this.port}`;
    }
};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App initialContests={window.initialData.contests} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that for some reason express is only rendering index.js. I think it may have something to do with my webpack config which has this file listed as the entry. I am not sure how to fix it still, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your config file look like? I can't help but feel like there's something else in your code interfering

Comment: I'll post that aswell

Comment: I see you're using JSX, which means you must be using Webpack or something of the like. Check out the output of those applications, and see if it looks right.

Also, I strongly advise you do not use the ` character, as that is generally an SQL quote denoting a table, or a value.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! I don't see anything wrong with the webpack output. But clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold can you see the issue now that I've updated above?

Comment: Your entry point is the main. So, make sure that the webpack config is saying the correct file is the main function. Have you verified that the code telling it to render at all is being called?

Comment: @JonathanSchmoid I don't think it is. The code for the entry point is under 'index.js' above. I'm not really sure how to write the code for it to render. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The abstracting of the app.js out of index.js seems a tad redundant. Pull all the code out of that first section, and put it into index.js. The entry point is supposed to be the initialization of the application, and firing up all the services. Splitting the file in two just makes it harder for you to understand in the future.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold When I put them into the same file I get a 'document is not defined' error. And it does not seem fixable.

Comment: The entry point you defined in the Webpack config file is the file that contains the unified code?

Comment: @JonathanSchmold Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Express with a template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html), you need to declare where your views are located with the `'views'` setting on your Express server.

Also make sure you assign your middleware prior to your routes where needed (ie. static content). Express evaluates Middleware and Routes top-down, so if you place your static content after a route, and that route depends on a static resource, it won't be made static before the route will need it.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const server = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337

// res.render() will now look in './views' for the templates
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
server.set('view engine', 'ejs')

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// Your Router Middleware/Routes goes here

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: This was all useful stuff to know, but it has not fixed my issue. Any ideas why its not rendering the content when I have separate ejs files for each page?

Comment: For both routes, does `content` get evaluated synchronously?

Comment: I believe they're synchronous. I've added more code above so hopefully you can see more.

Comment: @anoop Your ejs syntax is incorrect. All ejs templates use `<%=` and `%>` to wrap injected data

Comment: I've changed that now aswell. When should the <%- syntax be used and when should the <%=. I'm not entirely clear on that.

Comment: @anoop there is no such syntax `<%-`, read the [ejs docs](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: @peteb Actually `<%-` is also supported. From the docs: `<%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)`
`<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template`

Comment: And to the OP's question: Use `<%-` when you wish to insert HTML into your document and `<%=` when you want things like `<` converted into `&lt;`

Comment: @RobRaisch any idea how to answer my main question?